# Calling Sever for Update using android? How to Architecture my Code?

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, android-syncadapter, scheduledexecutorservice

Scenario: I have an application that recieves data from Cloud, the cloud is receives data from Sensors in a fish farm(Internet of things).My job is to recieve data from cloud and update my user interface every second.

How do I Architecture? what components should I use?? is it mandatory to use ContentProvider, syncAdapter ??

I am using Retrofit Library and How to call this api? should i call it in my activity?

Comment: "My job is to recieve data from cloud and update my user interface every second" -- unless the device is always plugged in, this will be terrible for the battery. "Is it better to use IntentService or JobScheduler or Boundservice? " -- in your case, none of them. You will need a foreground regular `Service`, using some in-process timing solution (e.g., `ScheduledExecutorService`).

Comment: what about using SyncAdapter??? can you give example ScheduledExecutorService?